# How can a Python Microservice verify requests using a JWT in an Authorization header?

Tags: python, jwt, openid-connect

The various python libraries for OpenID 2 or OIDC seem to be focused on full web clients implemented in Python which participate in the full OAUTH2 dance for login.  How can an API microservice implemented in Python and Flask validate incoming requests that have a JWT provided as a Bearer token in an `Authorization` header, and then pull claim information out of the JWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWTs are actually pretty simple things, so it's fairly straightforward to write your own code for dealing with them. That said, why reinvent the wheel? I'd suggest the `pyjwt` library (https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Does most everything you could want.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some insight from protocol perspective.

JWT validation is defined by JWT specification itself. [RFC7519 JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) contains section [7.2.  Validating a JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-7) which specify what you must do in token receiving endpoint. I welcome you to go through it so you have correct understanding and won't create security loopholes.

Of course, language implementations are readily available as other answers. But in summary these are the steps.

- Extract JWT parts : **Header**, **Body** and **signature**
- Go through Header contents and identify JWT type and it's type ([JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515.html) vs [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516.html))
- Validate signature OR validate  encryption
- Decode and read body with custom or desired validations

Once you have claims from body, it's up to you to decide. But if you are receiving OIDC ID token, then validate it against [specification's guide](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation)